# CSRF Protections with AJAX & FORM - CodeIgniter - Not Sending

Tags: php, ajax, forms, codeigniter, csrf

In the beginning I turned off my CSRF just for simplicity reasons to make my form / ajax work. Now when I turned it on and tried to use the  inputs and stuff for CSRF nothing will work. My form doesn't submit or when It does my whole page refreshes which I can't let that happen. Here is my current code.

```
form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="vip_text_box" id="vip" value="<?php echo $total_amount ?>"> <br><br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Redeem" onclick="return rebate_amount()">
  <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>">
</form>
```

And the AJAX:

```
function rebate_amount(){

  var value = document.getElementById('vip').value;
  var datastring = 'vip='+value;
  var url = base_url + '/index.php/home/redeeming_form_value';

  $.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url : url,
    data: datastring,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){

      $('#vip_point_redeeming').html(html);

    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

Keep in mind. This all works when CSRF is off in the config file. But I think theres a problem here with CSRF with form / ajax.

Comment: Your AJAX request constructs a POST operation but fails to provide the CSRF token. When CodeIgniter receives the POST operation, it fails to find the TOKEN and shuts everything down before you have a chance to run any code.

Answer (score 2):

You should also include `csrf_token` with data

**500 internal server error**

> Your AJAX request constructs a POST operation but fails to provide the
>   CSRF token. When CodeIgniter receives the POST operation, it fails to
>   find the TOKEN and shuts everything down before you have a chance to
>   run any code, thus you receive 500 internal server error

**Either you make**

```
data :  $("#your_form").serialize();
```

**OR**

```
data: {
        '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>':'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>',

           /*....your data....*/
           vip:document.getElementById('vip').value
       },
```

**Your function would look somewhat**

```
function rebate_amount(){

var url = base_url + '/index.php/home/redeeming_form_value';

$.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url : url,
    data: {
    '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>':'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>',

       /*....your data....*/
       vip:document.getElementById('vip').value
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
      $('#vip_point_redeeming').html(html);
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

Comment: This looks pretty good. Not sure where the AJAX code gets defined, but you need for CodeIgniter to feed the CSRF token into it so you can pass it on with the POST data.

Comment: I assume ajax code is defined in view, so when user loads view by `$this->load->view(..)`,  data can be prefilled with token and value, if no he still can serialize

Comment: A reasonable assumption. I haven't tested it. I was just trying to provide clarifying text for the OP as your post is fairly terse.

Comment: thanks for you comment, If you permit I will include you comment, so that answer will be more clearer to the user

Comment: Thank you so much, so kind of you.